# GNSS enabled Android camera app that stores the pitch, roll, and yaw of the image

Tags: android, camera, gps

I have developed Python scripts to extract locations, pitch, roll, and yaw from DJI drone images and automatically georeference those images.  I would like to be able to do the same with my phone camera.  I have installed on my phone GPS Essential which will geotag an image.  GPS Essentials will also display the camera pitch, roll, and yaw on a heads-up display on their camera but it does not write those values to the camera's metadata.  I am looking for an Android camera app that will store geotag data in addition to the pitch, roll, and yaw at the time of image capture.

Comment: Not sure if it covers GNSS, but you could give [OpenCamera Sensors](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/com.opencamera_extended.app) a try. Going by the description, it seems to record quite a few sensor data along in the image's metadata.

Comment: Thanks, @Izzy.  That was promising but OpenCamera-Sensor appears to only support sensor values for video.

Comment: Thanks again, @Izzy.  I found that the parent app to OpenCamera Sensor called Open Camera (available on Google Play) has a option to record the pitch, roll, and yaw to the EXIF header under the 'User Comment' EXIF tag.  Perfect!  If you want to post your solution as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Wow, it does? Never noticed. And yes, in fact that's the app I use on all of my devices all those years… Can you tell me the steps to find that setting? I just walked all its settings and didn't find them (pointer: I'm using the app from F-Droid, as usual). No special "Exif" section found – only Creator and Copyright.

Comment: I have a newly downloaded version from Google Play.  Camera Controls (gear icon) Then under Photo and Video Settings - Location Settings - Check 'Store yaw, pitch, and roll'.

Comment: Is that what's called [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles)? Then the reason I missed it is that in German, it doesn't say anything about "yaw, pitch and roll", but only gives that term with the explanation "Drehlage des Gerätes" ("Rotational position of the device"). Sounds like that matches, indeed – thanks for pointing out! TIL :)

Comment: @swapnil-kothari If you think of the app/site you discovered that could display the yaw/roll data, please add a comment to help anyone interested.  You'll need to attain a tiny bit of rep to post a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we figured in the comments on the question, **[Open Camera](https://opencamera.org.uk/)** seems to fit the bill.
This Android app is open source and available [at F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/net.sourceforge.opencamera/) as well as [at Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera).
I can highly recommend this app, using it for years: best quality, no nagging (neither ads nor tracking), very configurable – feature-rich but still not bloated or overgrown. You can even use an external microphone for video recordings if you wish.

Now for the special feature you requested I never noticed *Open Camera* well supports.
It can be found in the settings (reachable via the "gear" icon in the camera overlay), right below "**Photo Settings" and "Video Settings**", inside the "Location Settings" item (see below screenshot).
In English it seems to use the phrase "Store yaw, pitch, and roll", while in other languages it might look different (e.g. in German it writes "*Eigentliche Eulerwinkel speichern*", which according to Wikipedia's [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) article seems to be exactly that.

[image: Open Camera Settings]
<sup>*Open Camera:* Settings screen</sup>